# Error validating CDATA elements with DTD - XML

Tags: xml, validation, dtd, cdata

I'm trying to validate some xml with a DTD I'm writing but I always get a validation error on the elements with CDATA data types. Like this

```
<!ELEMENT title (#CDATA)>
```

I've tried validating using textmate xml validation (XMLlint) and online validators (w3Schools) and I always get this error:

```
error: ContentDecl : Name or '(' expected
```

Can anybody explain what's going on here?

Cheers

Example of full xml and dtd (I took this from [here](http://www.sitepoint.com/xml-dtds-xml-schema/) so I'd expect it to be valid):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>   
<!DOCTYPE bookstore [   
  <!ELEMENT bookstore (name,topic+)>   
  <!ELEMENT topic (name,book*)>   
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT book (title,author)>   
  <!ELEMENT title (#CDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT author (#CDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ATTLIST book isbn CDATA "0">   
  ]>   
<bookstore>   
  <name>Mike's Store</name>   
  <topic>   
    <name>XML</name>   
    <book isbn="123-456-789">   
      <title>Mike's Guide To DTD's and XML Schemas<</title>   
      <author>Mike Jervis</author>   
    </book>   
  </topic>   
</bookstore>
```

Comment: Just found this in the XMLlint docs: --nocdata
Substitute CDATA section by equivalent text nodes.

Answer (score 5):

Well, the example was a bad one, there's no such thing as `(#CDATA)` for the element content model.

```
  <!DOCTYPE bookstore [   
  <!ELEMENT bookstore (name,topic+)>   
  <!ELEMENT topic (name,book*)>   
  <!ELEMENT name (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT book (title,author)>   
  <!ELEMENT title (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT author (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ELEMENT isbn (#PCDATA)>   
  <!ATTLIST book isbn CDATA "0">   
  ]>   
<bookstore>   
  <name>Mike's Store</name>   
  <topic>   
    <name>XML</name>   
    <book isbn="123-456-789">   
      <title>Mike's Guide To DTD's and XML Schemas</title>   
      <author>Mike Jervis</author>   
   </book>   
  </topic>   
</bookstore>
```

**UPDATE:**

The W3C XML specification, http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126, clearly does not allow `#CDATA` in the content model for elements. Start at production [45](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-elementdecl) and follow throught to production  [51](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/REC-xml-20081126/#NT-Mixed).

Comment: oh, that's strange. The top result in google says there is http://www.xmlfiles.com/dtd/dtd_elements.asp

Comment: I don't know how they can come to that conclusion. See update.

Comment: +1 for a good answer. @PigChicken - That XML is definitely invalid. There is no such thing as `#CDATA`. The only time you'll see something similar is in an `ATTLIST` declaration for the attribute type. It's written as `CDATA` though, not `#CDATA`. Also, the XML is not even well formed; there is an extra `<` just inside the `</title>` tag. forty-two caught that one as well but didn't mention it in his/her answer. I'm not sure if I would use anything coming from that website if I were you.

Comment: @DevNull Exactly, being #1 on google search results doesn't necessarily mean you're right!

Comment: In SGML element content can be declared as `CDATA` (for example the `<script>` element in HTML). In XML this is not allowed. But in such case there should not be a `#` character in the declaration. Besides that hash character, `<!ELEMENT title (#CDATA)>` is a syntax error because of the parentheses. It actually means that `<title>` has a child element called `<#CDATA>` and `#` is not an allowed name character.